# Inserting values in to table in mysql using python shows no syntax error , but the record is not getting updated on db

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm a newbie to python and i am trying to insert some data in to a mysql table .Seems the query executed with out any issues, however i don't see any record added on to the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Aditya

```
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='sandboxbeta2503', password='XXX',
                                       host='myreleasebox.com',
                                       database='iaas')
            print ("Updating the history in bulk_notification_history")
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")
            notification_type = "Notify Inactive users"
            usercount= 45
            query = ("INSERT INTO iaas.bulk_notification_history"
                "(nty_date,notification_type,user_count)"
                "VALUES (%s,%s,%s)")             
           data = (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),notification_type, usercount)  
           linker1 = cursor.execute(query,data)   
           print (linker1) 
           cursor.close()
           connection.close()
```

Comment: seems that there is an issue in `INSERT` query.. please check the syntax after `VALUES` clause

Comment: I have ran the same set of commands on the python interactive terminal 
`>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")
>>> notification_type = "Notify Inactive users"
>>> usercount = 45
>>> query = "INSERT INTO iaas.bulk_notification_history (nty_date,notification_type,user_count) VALUES ('%s','%s',%d)" %(timestamp,notification_type,usercount)
>>>linker1 = cursor.execute(query)
>>> linker1
>>> print (linker1)
None`

Comment: @bluto I did tried the same code on python console seems it returned None with out any syntax errors

Comment: _Never_ use string formatting to create sql queries!!! use [`cursor.execute(query, parameters)`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14).

Comment: Seems this has issues again "
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"

`query = ("""INSERT INTO iaas.bulk_notification_history "
                    "(nty_date,notification_type,user_count)"
                    "VALUES (%s, %s, %d)""")             
            data = (timestamp, notification_type, usercount)
            print (query)    
            linker1 = cursor.execute(query,data)   
            print (linker1)`